# Search array, find elements with ids specified another array, extract a property from the results

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two arrays,

```
array1 = [{name: "a", id: 1},{name: "b", id: 2},{name: "c", id: 3}]
```

and

```
array2 = [1, 2] // --which are the ids
```

I want to return a new array (array3) to display `["a", "b"]` and if `array2 = [1,3]` then array3 should be `["a", "c"]`

In other words, I would like to create a new array, with the `names`, corresponding to its `id`.

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let a1 = [{name:'a', id:1},{name:'b', id:2},{name:'c', id:3}]
let a2 = [1,3]

let a3 = a1.reduce((carry, current) => {
    if (a2.includes(current.id)) {
        carry.push(current.name)
    }
    
    return carry
}, [])

alert(a3)
```

Comment: could you also tell me how to make the toaster notif stay longer , it only stays for 2 secs, i want it to stay longer

Answer (score 1):

User [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select the elements that meet your criteria, and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the property you want.

```
const array1 = [{name:"a", id:1},{name:"b", id:2},{name:"c", id:3}];
const array2=[1,2];
const array3 = array1.filter(i => array2.includes(i.id)).map(i => i.name);
```

`array3` will contain `["a", "b"]`

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and perform the below:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array1.length(); ++i){
  for(int j = 0; j<array2.length(); ++j){
    if (array1[i].id==array2[j]){
      array3[j] = array[i].name;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this is simple and it helps!